# Compute percent in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here's the query:

```
select
(
SELECT     COUNT(*)
FROM         Sending s
WHERE     (ConfID = 1) AND (Status = 1)
)
/
(
 (
 SELECT     COUNT(*)
 FROM         Numbers
 WHERE     (ConfID = 1)
 )
 /
 100
)
```

I want to compute percent. For instance, if query

```
SELECT     COUNT(*)
     FROM         Numbers
     WHERE     (ConfID = 1)
```

gives 100 and the another one

```
 SELECT     COUNT(*)
    FROM         Sending s
    WHERE     (ConfID = 1) AND (Status = 1)
```

results 50 the result query should return 50, which means 50%. But is first query results with 2 and second returns 10000 the result query returns 0. I think I should define somehow to return float number or so on.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try (100*FIRST_QUERY)/SECOND_QUERY?

Comment: @Laurent' Isn't `(100*FIRST_QUERY)/SECOND_QUERY` the same as `(FIRST_QUERY)/(SECOND_QUERY/100)`?

Comment: @Benoit I know, look at my answer. Laurent's suggestion didn't work either (look at EmptyStack's answer and OP's comment). My point is: even if Laurent's suggestion had worked, it would be misleading. Do not rework your math to try and fool data types. Work with the right data types instead.

Comment: I only meant to avoid rounding errors... (i.e. 2/100 = 0 if all types are integers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try dividing by `100.0` instead of `100`. That will force a cast to floating point data type:

```
select
(
SELECT     COUNT(*)
FROM         Sending s
WHERE     (ConfID = 1) AND (Status = 1)
)
/
(
 (
 SELECT     COUNT(*)
 FROM         Numbers
 WHERE     (ConfID = 1)
 )
 /
 100.0
)
```

Comment: Diamond! Explicitly that I need! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE status WHEN 1 THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*)
  FROM numbers
 WHERE confid = 1
```

Comment: This was also my initial idea, problem is that the OP is selecting from 2 different tables

Comment: You are already summing up 100s. However, your result division will be `200 / 10000 = 0.02` which in integer division will round to `0`. You need to sum up `100.0`

Comment: @Adrian: except if I want a value that rounds to an integer (usually this is enough feedback to a user). Otherwise you're right!

Comment: @t-clausen.dk : right I hadn't seen that from the original question